# Interpreting an expression

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

When reducing and simplifying a complex algebraic inequality I get an expression containing

`Root[-a + b #1^3 &, 1] < β < (a/b)`

How can I interpret the first term in the inequality? The 1st root of some function? Why not putting it explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why not putting it explicitly?

From help,

> Root "Represents the exact k^th root of the polynomial equation
> f[x]==0"

This can be rewritten as follows

```
 expr = Root[-a+b#1^3&,1]< \[Beta] < (a/b)
 expr // ToRadicals
```

[image]

From help on `ToRadicals` it says

> attempts to express all Root objects in expr in terms of radicals.

To try to answer the comment:

> how the expression Root[-a+b#1^3&,1] results in the fraction shown
> above?

The above answer comes from, when rewriting `Root[-a + b #1^3 &, 1]` as

```
 Solve[-a + b*x^3 == 0, x]
```

Where `#1^3` becomes `x^3`. Now `Root[....,1]` says the `first` root. i.e. the first root of `-a + b*x^3 == 0`.  Which is

```
 Solve[-a + b*x^3 == 0, x]
```

[image]

Now the question might be, since there are 3 roots to the cubic, why the first root was choosing `x -> ((-1)^(2/3) a^(1/3))/b^(1/3)` and not `x -> a^(1/3)/b^(1/3)` ?  It looks like some internal ordering is used to decide which is the *first root*. As `Root[-a + b #1^3 &, 3] // ToRadicals` gives `a^(1/3)/b^(1/3)`

Comment: Dear @Nasser, you actually answered my question, but may I ask you to add a couple of words on how the expression Root[-a+b#1^3&,1] results in the fraction shown above? I'm a novice in Mathematica and I have hard time trying to decode this...

Comment: @Dmitry I tried to answer you comment in the post.

Comment: Ah, now I understand where this root comes from. That was the missing piece in the puzzle :)